# Renaming input file before uploading with jquery and laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I want to rename input file to be uploaded before sending to laravel.

Basically, i found an another way to rename the file in laravel but in this question I want to rename the file before sending to laravel.

In my case, I'm using [jquery upload file](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php), and now I want the input file to be renamed before uploading it. I want to get the new file name that I used to insert in the hidden input text.

Is there any solution to solve this kind of matter?
By the way, thank you in advance! ^_^

Comment: The answer is no.. you can't.. because of security reasons. What if a programmer would decide to rename the file to `C:/Windows/...`, that means that anyone could upload whatever files he wants without letting the user know it..

Comment: I actually need is changing the filename of the file before uploaded in laravel. The scenario is when the user select a file automatically rename the file of the certain file that user upload then I used in the laravel controller is getClientOriginalName()

Comment: yes.. I understood it perfectly but you can't.. you can only rename it in backend.. not in frontend

Comment: Got it, I already rename it on backend but i actually need is on the frontend side and i taught there's a way to rename the filename in frontend. Byt the way, thank you for your help. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check this: [File Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#files)

as per this doc you can do this as follow:

```
$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

where $fileName is an optional parameter that renames the file.

so you can use this like:

```
$fileName = str_random(30);    // any random string
```

then pass this as above.

Comment: Yes, I already used that way. But in my case, I want to rename the file before sending to laravel. I think you got confused on my question but in the whole of this matter I need to rename the filename before uploading to larevel and with the used of jquery upload file by Ravishanker Kusuma